# Require tool to trace the LInq Queries in Oracle

Tags: oracle, linq, entity-framework, oracle11g, linq-to-entities

i am working entity framework with oracle data connection.

Can anyone suggest tool to get the LINQ queries executed in oracle.

I am looking similar tools like SQL profile in Oracle to trace and execute the queries.

Comment: Look at [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of such a tool, but if you are using Entity Framework 6 and you can modify the application code, you can trace the queries by using the builtin logging.

For example, to output all queries to the console, you can use:

```cs
context.Database.Log = Console.Write;
```

For more details check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx.